# mistake in adding the string numbers in a vector

Tags: c++

I'm reading words from a file, and the output should be the word and the line numbers the word appeared in. My code works well, but I'm having problem in the vector in which I store the line numbers of each word.

For example, the text file:

```
I am for truth
no matter who tells it,
I am for justice,
no matter who it is for or against
Malcom X
```

The output I get:

```
I 13
am 1133
for 111333444444
truth 1111
no 24
matter 2244
who 222444
tells 2222
it 222224444
justice 3333
is 44444
or 4444444
against 44444444
Malcom 5
X 55
```

And the output I was expecting:

```
against 4 
matter 2, 4
am 1, 3 
no 2, 4
for 1, 3, 4 
or 4
I 1, 3 
tells 2
is 4 
truth 1
it 2, 4 
who 2,4
justice 3 
X 5
Malcolm 5
```

And here is my code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    fstream infile ;
    BSTFCI <string>* bst = new BSTFCI<string>();
    string word;
    string line;
    vector <string>words;
    vector <string>line_no;
    int count = 0;
    infile.open("test.txt" , ios::in);
    if(infile.fail())
    {
      cout<<"Error Opening file"<<endl;
      return 0;
    }

    while(getline(infile , line))
    {
        ++count;
        istringstream buffer(line);
        ostringstream counter;
        while (buffer >> word)
        {

            for(int i=0 ; i<word.size();i++) {
                if(ispunct(word[i]))
                word.erase(i,1);        
            }

            if(!bst->search(word)) {
                bst->insert(word);
                words.push_back(word);
                counter << count;
                line_no.push_back(counter.str());
            } else {
                counter<<count;
                for(int k=0;k<words.size();k++) {
                    if(word==words.at(k))
                        line_no.at(k)+=counter.str();
                }
            } 

        }
    }

    for(int i=0;i<words.size();i++)
       cout << words.at(i) << " " << line_no.at(i) << endl;

    infile.close();
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Please, improve your indentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try deleting `counter<<count`. It look to me the reason for the mistake. if it wont work delete `count++;`